# How to use MS Access Dateserial, Month, Weekday in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I'm trying to convert my MS Access query That uses Dateserial, Month, and Weekday functions to work in SQL Server 2008.

With the following values in a record: 
[dbo_TBL_TEST].[MFG_YYYY] = "2012"
[dbo_TBL_TEST].[MFG_WW] = "43"

The result from the following MS Access Query expression will be 82.

```
MFG_Test_INDEX: (Month(DateSerial(Val([dbo_TBL_TEST].[MFG_YYYY]),1,1)-Weekday(DateSerial(Val([dbo_TBL_TEST].[MFG_YYYY]),1,3))+(Val([dbo_TBL_TEST].[MFG_WW])*7))+(Val([dbo_TBL_TEST].[MFG_YYYY])-2006)*12)
```

Is there a way to do this in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: perhaps you could explain what the expression is supposed to do, rather than expecting us to work it out!

Comment: This formula takes the Year (MFG_YYYY) and Work Week (MFG_WW) the product was manufactured and returns the number of months since Jan 2006 (This uses the ISO date format).

Comment: Here is how it's done in Excel:

Comment: Here is how to convert an ISO week number to month in Excel (using the above values for year and Work Week):  =MONTH(DATE(2012,1,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(2012,1,3))+43*7).   Now you just need to add the number of months since Jan 2006: (2012-2006)*12.... to get the results 82.

Comment: Seems that SQL is lacking the necessary functions to easily perform what can be done in Access and Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it in SQL-Server 2008....
This returns the number of months from the current year,work week (MFG_YYYY,MFG_WW) since Jan 2006 using the ISO 8601 standard.

```
DATEPART ( Month, Dateadd(weekday,+4,Dateadd(day,-1,DATEADD(DAY, 7 * MFG_WW,1,2) + DATEDIFF(DAY, 4, DATEADD(YEAR, MFG_YYYY - 1900, 7)) / 7 * 7, 1 - 8))))+((DATEPART ( Year, Dateadd(weekday,+4,Dateadd(day,-1,DATEADD(DAY, 7 * MFG_WW + DATEDIFF(DAY, 4, DATEADD(YEAR, MFG_YYYY - 1900, 7)) / 7 * 7, 1 - 8))))-2006)*12) AS MFG_Index
```

Answer (score 1):

T-SQL has a [`MONTH()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) function. It doesn't have a direct `DateSerial()` equivalent, but you could "glue together" the date string and then use [`CAST()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to convert it to the appropriate date type. And in place of `Weekday()` you can use [`DATEPART(dw, datevalue)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). Details on these and other T-SQL date functions are available [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).